# Filter on Output clause sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use a filter on an OUTPUT clause in t-sql.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
Insert into tbl_1(col1,col2)
Output Inserted.col1 into #tbl_temp 
**where col1 > 0**
select col3, col4
from tbl_2
```

For performance reasons I don't want to use two insert statements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
insert into #tbl_temp
select col1
from
  (
    insert into tbl_1(col1,col2) 
    output Inserted.col1
    select col3, col4 
    from tbl_2
  ) as T
where T.col1 > 0
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. It feels - so dirty - to have an updating action as a subqeury.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever – Example `K` from this page does just that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: @Damien, @Carovei – It is documented here under `<dml_statement_with_output_clause>`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: I made some tests today and this form of insert works worst (speaking in execution time) than the situation when we use 2 inserts. Maybe it has some special cases when it should be used, but for now I will use the 2 insert statements method :D