# MERGE - conditional "WHEN MATCHED" OUTPUT

Tags: t-sql, merge, sql-server-2014

The following code shows two `WHEN MATCHED`-clauses.
The first one matches when only the `DATETIME`-column 'updatedAt' is changed.
This should update the target, however I don't want this marked in the `OUTPUT`. The second one matches when there are other changes in the given match, this should lead to an `OUTPUT`.

```
MERGE [Target].dbo.[clients] AS target
USING [Source].dbo.[clients] AS source
ON target.[objectId]=source.[objectId]
WHEN MATCHED AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT source.firstName, ...
                    EXCEPT
                    SELECT target.firstName, ...
                ) AND source.updatedAt <> target.updatedAt
THEN 
    UPDATE SET --THIS UPDATE SHOULD NOT LEAD TO AN OUTPUT WITH $ACTION = 'UPDATE'
        target.updatedAt = source.updatedAt
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (
                    SELECT source.firstName, ... , source.updatedAt
                    EXCEPT
                    SELECT target.firstName, ... , target.updatedAt
                )
THEN
    UPDATE SET --THIS UPDATE SHOULD LEAD TO AN OUTPUT WITH $ACTION = 'UPDATE'
        target.[firstName]=source.[firstName], ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN
    INSERT ([objectId],[firstName], ... ,[updatedAt]) VALUES ([objectId],[firstName], ... ,[updatedAt])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
THEN
    DELETE

OUTPUT 
    $ACTION ChangeType
    , ISNULL(
        inserted.objectId
        , deleted.objectId
    ) AS objectId
    , GETDATE() AS DateTimeChanged
;
```

This is achievable by outputting all source and target columns and putting the `MERGE` in a subquery, to make the comparison in a main query, e.g.:

```
WHERE NOT (
    [ChangeType]='UPDATE' 
    AND [src objectId]=[tgt objectId] 
    AND [src firstName]=[tgt firstName] 
    AND ... 
    AND [src updatedAt]<>[tgt updatedAt]
)
```

However, I feel there should be a better way, since I am able to declare two different `WHEN MATCHED`-clauses. Is there any better way?

Comment: To clarify, you want to update a record but not have it show as an update in the output?  You can't stop it being in the output altogether but you could insert it into a temp table with a filter.  This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660267/filter-on-output-clause-sql) might help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your example is correct, because you have two conditional WHEN MATCHED clauses.

as per Books online: [Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  (emphasis mine)

> WHEN MATCHED THEN < merge_matched >
>    Specifies that all rows of
>   *target_table, which match the rows returned by  ON , and satisfy any additional search condition,
>   are either updated or deleted according to the  clause.
>
> The MERGE statement can have, **at most, two WHEN MATCHED** clauses. If
>   two clauses are specified, the **first clause must be accompanied by an
>   AND  clause.** For any given row, the **second WHEN
>   MATCHED clause is only applied if the first isn't.** If there are two
>   WHEN MATCHED clauses, **one must specify an UPDATE action and one must
>   specify a DELETE action.** When UPDATE is specified in the
>    clause, and more than one row of 
>   matches a row in target_table based on , SQL
>   Server returns an error. The MERGE statement can't update the same row
>   more than once, or update and delete the same row.

I've also tried your code

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

CREATE TABLE TargetClients
(
    objectId BIGINT
    , firstName VARCHAR(50)
    , updatedAt DATETIME2(0)

)

CREATE TABLE SourceClients
(
    objectId BIGINT
    , firstName VARCHAR(50)
    , updatedAt DATETIME2(0)

)

go

MERGE TargetClients AS target
USING SourceClients AS source
ON target.[objectId]=source.[objectId]
WHEN MATCHED AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT source.firstName
                    EXCEPT
                    SELECT target.firstName
                ) AND source.updatedAt <> target.updatedAt
THEN 
    UPDATE SET --THIS UPDATE SHOULD NOT LEAD TO AN OUTPUT WITH $ACTION = 'UPDATE'
        target.updatedAt = source.updatedAt
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (
                    SELECT source.firstName, source.updatedAt
                    EXCEPT
                    SELECT target.firstName, target.updatedAt
                )
THEN
    UPDATE SET --THIS UPDATE SHOULD LEAD TO AN OUTPUT WITH $ACTION = 'UPDATE'
        target.[firstName]=source.[firstName]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN
    INSERT ([objectId],[firstName], [updatedAt]) VALUES ([objectId],[firstName], [updatedAt])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
THEN
    DELETE

OUTPUT 
    $ACTION ChangeType
    , ISNULL(
        inserted.objectId
        , deleted.objectId
    ) AS objectId
    , GETDATE() AS DateTimeChanged
;



rollback
```

And it showed me the error

> Msg 10714, Level 15, State 1, Line 33 An action of type 'WHEN MATCHED'
>   cannot appear more than once in a 'UPDATE' clause of a MERGE
>   statement.

One possible solution for you would be to use CASE statement inside the `Merge_matched` clause and use an extra column as a flag.